# Backup in Mysql periodically

Tags: mysql, data-backup

I have trouble scheduling a backup in mysql periodically, most of the tools do not recognize the geometric field, for example navicat which says

> Can not get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field

others simply do not create the table or do not fill the field with the information, someone knows a solution that is free and effective for this problem

Comment: What Operating System?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention, the database is in windows version of mysql is 5.5.25, the problem is that all that encounter to generate program the dump me out mistakes or simply ignore the field

Comment: You might have some spatial data with null values http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5875327/spatial-index-in-mysql-error-cannot-get-geometry-object-from-data-you-send-t